# How to point to a different database in oracle APEX v 5.x?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have Oracle APEX configured on my laptop pointing to Oracle express DB on my laptop also.

I want to point to a different database on another server (specifically Oracle eBusiness suite database). How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does all the data live in the other database?  Or does most of the data live in your local database and you just need to pull a bit of data from the other database?

If you are building applications that interact primarily with the data in the Oracle eBusiness Suite database, you'd realistically want to install APEX (if it is not already installed there) in the Oracle eBusiness Suite database and build your APEX application there.  If you are building applications that interact primarily with data in your local database and you just need to pull a bit of data from the eBusiness Suite database, you can create a database link in your local database that connects to the remote database and reference objects over the database link.